# Authorize.net accept js - Own payment form not working in localhost

Tags: php, magento2, payment-gateway, authorize.net, accept.js

I have integrated `authorize.net` accept js payment option on my local magento site.

First of all, in my local site, I have integrated the hosted payment form (predefined payment form). It is working fine. It returns a successful transaction message.

And now I'm gonna work with my own payment form, it requires https connection.
  I just followed this [doc](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html). 
And I have used the same example that was mentioned in this doc.

I'm working on my local server. Once these were working fine means only, I can push to live server.

So, now my doubt is - why hosted payment form working in a local server ( unsecure connection - http) and why my custom form is not working in my local server?

It returns `E_WC_02` error while using a custom payment form. I want to check this custom payment form in my local server also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using sandbox or live? because afaik accept.js doesn't need https on sandbox.

Comment: Now I'm using Sandbox account only. So any other idea to use the custom payment form with `http` connection.

Answer (score 2):

I have currently solved this issue by using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). I hope this will be helpful to others. Recently I got this solution.

After installing this ngrok in my local server and then I have changed my `web/secure/base_url` and `web/unsecure/base_url` in `core_config_data` table.
i.e, to replace a 
http://localhost to **http://2b45c5ab.ngrok.io**  and https://localhost to **https://2b45c5ab.ngrok.io**

Thanks.